# Write text and save dialog

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile 
  
root = Tk() 
root.geometry('200x150') 

Text = ['word','great','text']

def save(): 
    text_file = asksaveasfile(title="Select Location", filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"),))

    with open(text_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(Text)


btn = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Save', command = lambda : save()) 
btn.pack(side = TOP, pady = 20)
  
mainloop()
```

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper

I have a list called Text. I want to print the contents of the list into a text file. What should I do?

Comment: Whats wrong with the code you have.

Comment: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper

Comment: I dont see how this code can produce this error as long as `Text` is a list

Comment: f.write("this is a text") does not accept this either

Comment: What is the error.

Comment: Unfortunately, Same error !

Comment: It shouldnt give any error. You are making some other mistake. Do you know we use `#` for comments in python and not `//`

Comment: Yes, I know. No "//" in original code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that works for me:

```py
lst = ['Hello There\n', 'How are ya\n', 'All good?\n']

def save(): 
    text_file = asksaveasfile(title="Select Location", filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"),))
     for line in lst:
         text_file.write(line) # Use str(line) if lst is of integers
```

The mistake is that `asksaveasfile` returns a `_io.TextIOWrapper` object, meaning its same as using `open(...)` one a file. What you wanted was `asksaveasfilename()` which will return the path of the object, then:

```py
def save(): 
    text_file = asksaveasfilename(title="Select Location", filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"),))
    with open(text_file, 'w') as f:     
        for line in lst:
            f.write(line) # Use str(line) if list of integers
```

Comment: It is working. Thank you very much. I am grateful to you.

Comment: text_file.write(line) will work here, but if the list had integers it wouldn't have worked. text_file.write(str(line)) is correct I think.

Comment: @Rysicin I provided a string of lists, but yes, with `int` you will need extra type casting.